# Cannot build Corda (release/os/4.6) on Ubuntu 20.04 due to failing tests (CryptoUtilsTest & NodeH2SecurityTests)

Tags: build, corda

I am trying to build Corda on Ubuntu 20.04. I have the latest sources from the git repo (release/os/4.6) and I run `./gradlew build` in the main folder. However the build fails during two tests (see the detail description below). Is there something that I'm missing? Are there some special flags that I should use for building Corda?

---

First, the test `test default SecureRandom uses platformSecureRandom` fails at the last assert, i.e.,

```
// in file net/corda/core/crypto/CryptoUtilsTest.kt
fun `test default SecureRandom uses platformSecureRandom`() {
  // [...]
  // Remove Corda Provider again and add it as the first Provider entry.
  Security.removeProvider(CordaSecurityProvider.PROVIDER_NAME)
  Security.insertProviderAt(CordaSecurityProvider(), 1) // This is base-1.
  val secureRandomRegisteredFirstCordaProvider = SecureRandom()
  assertEquals(PlatformSecureRandomService.algorithm, secureRandomRegisteredFirstCordaProvider.algorithm)
}
```

The reason for the failed test is `Expected <CordaPRNG>, actual <SHA1PRNG>.`.
For some reason, the test is successful if before inserting the provider, I call the `getServices()` method, i.e.,

```
val provider = CordaSecurityProvider()
provider.getServices()
Security.insertProviderAt(provider, 1) // This is base-1.
```

I also tried to get the service `SecureRandom.CordaPRNG` directly from the provider and it works, i.e,

```
println(provider.getService("SecureRandom", "CordaPRNG"))
```

prints out `Corda: SecureRandom.CordaPRNG -> javaClass`

---

Second, the test `h2 server on the host IP requires non-default database password` fails since it expects a `CouldNotCreateDataSourceException`, but it gets a `NullPointerException` instead, i.e.,

```
// in file net/corda/node/internal/NodeH2SecurityTests.kt
fun `h2 server on the host IP requires non-default database password`() {
  // [...]
  address = NetworkHostAndPort(InetAddress.getLocalHost().hostAddress, 1080)
  val node = MockNode()

  val exception = assertFailsWith(CouldNotCreateDataSourceException::class) {
    node.startDb()
  }
  // [...]
}
```

The problem is that the `address` is `127.0.1.1:1080`, which means that `net/corda/node/internal/Node.kt::startDatabase()` does not throw `CouldNotCreateDataSourceException` since the condition to enter the branch

```
if (!InetAddress.getByName(effectiveH2Settings.address.host).isLoopbackAddress
    && configuration.dataSourceProperties.getProperty("dataSource.password").isBlank()) {
  throw CouldNotCreateDataSourceException()
}
```

is not satisfied. Instead it calls `toString()` on the parent of the path given by the DB name; the parent is null, and thus, it throws `NullPointerException`, i.e.,

```
val databaseName = databaseUrl.removePrefix(h2Prefix).substringBefore(';')
// databaseName=my_file
val baseDir = Paths.get(databaseName).parent.toString()
```

Comment: Corda 4.6 is not yet final, so I suggest you to start from release 4.5 and follow the development environment setup https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/getting-set-up.html . If you really want to build the source code yourself, please follow this instructions https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/building-corda.html#debianubuntu-linux (based on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Ubuntu 20 is not mentioned, so I would not used it). You should not have any issue with those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there't a LOT of reasons that building Corda from source might not work.

Here are my recommendations:

- it could be a java issue, there's a docs page on the specific version of java 8 that you need to use, (latest java support is on the roadmap for corda 5 ) Here's the docs page on that https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/getting-set-up.html
- Like Alessandro said, you'll want to be aware that 4.6 isn't generally available yet so there may well be bugs and problems in the code until the release. In addition just take another look at the docs page on building corda (here: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/building-corda.html#debianubuntu-linux), it's mentioned to use 18.04 but not the latest linux, as there might be some random clib things that could get in the way there.

Good luck to you.